# Getting Data from multiple tables SQLite

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

I have an android application that has 2 tables, one table stores posts and the other table stores images of the posts incase it has an image, changes are not all posts will have images, if a post has an image its primary key will be stored in the foreign Key table, when loading the posts I have to get all posts wether with image or not then check in the image table to see which posts have images and add the images to the posts below is a graphical overview of my tables

Post Table

```
`|post_id |post | post_description|
 |--------|-----|-----------------|
 |        |     |                 |`
```

Image Table

```
  `|img_id  |fk_postID | imagePath       |
   |--------|----------|-----------------|
   |        |          |                 |`
```

I could have used a join like 
        `Query = "SELECT post_id, post, post_description, imagePath FROM PostTable,

                ImageTable, Where PostTable.post_id = ImageTable.fk_postID;`

but this query is only returning posts with images and forgeting about posts without images, How can I get all posts be it with image or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: first off the join syntax you are using needs to be tweaked using join and on. Thus explicit join syntax that is modern. Then move to a `left join`

Comment: could you help with the code please? I am not so good in sql so I really dont get u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, you asked, so give this a whirl, see if you like the output

```
SELECT pt.post_id, pt.post, pt.post_description, im.imagePath 
FROM PostTable pt
left join ImageTable im
on im.fk_postID=pt.post_id
```

It will bring along for the ride the right table (ImageTable) of those posts that don't have images.

Uses table **aliases** (`pt` and `im`). That helps to be explicit which table the columns come from on the first line in case there are common column names in both, plus a little less typing.

Untested

reference [Mysql Left Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html)

Comment: Oh Man I typed all that, I wish I had seen this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Left join and that will result all entries from left table and matched entries from right table.

```
SELECT posttable.postid,posttable.post,posttable.postdescription, imagetable.imageid,imagetable.fkpostid,imagetable.imagepath
FROM posttable
LEFT JOIN imagetable
ON posttable.postid=imagetable.fkpostid
ORDER BY posttable.postid;
```

Code should look like that.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp