# mySQL query with Woocommerce - Ambiguous Column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to run an SQL query on my Woocommerce shop that outputs all customers names (first and last) who have purchased a certain set of items and the quantity ordered.  The schema is standard Wordpress/Woocommerce. My first query (below) worked, but doesn't output quantity ordered:

```
SELECT  `meta_value`,  `post_id`, `order_item_name` 
FROM  `wp_postmeta` AS pm  
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON pm.post_id = oi.order_id 
WHERE  `order_item_name` LIKE  'Photo%' AND  `meta_key` LIKE  '%shipping%name'
```

When trying to add the quantity to the query, I keep getting ambiguous column errors `Column 'meta_value' in field list is ambiguous`. When trying to add an alias to the table/column in various combinations, I get unknown column errors `Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.meta_value' in 'field list'`.  This is my updated query:

```
SELECT  `meta_value` ,  `post_id` ,  `order_item_name`, `om.meta_key`
FROM  `wp_postmeta` AS pm
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON pm.post_id = oi.order_id
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as om ON pm.order_item_id=om.order_item_id
WHERE `order_item_name` LIKE  'Photo%'
AND `pm.meta_key` LIKE  '%shipping%name'
AND `om.meta_key` LIKE '_qty'
```

Comment: best to alias your tables and specify which columns are coming from which throughout the query. The error message speaks for itself. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33633569  The server found more than one table with a common column name (used directly by you), so it is ambiguous

Comment: When I do that I get unknown column errors as stated above.

Comment: alright the columns don't exist. examine schema. It doesn't go from Ambiguous to column does not exist without a typo, in my mind

Comment: you are both using and not using aliases. Use them throughout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an alias, `pm` in your case, you can not also use the table name `wp_postmeta`

Use

```
SELECT  `pm`.`meta_value`,  `post_id`, `order_item_name` 
FROM  `wp_postmeta` AS pm  
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON pm.post_id = oi.order_id 
WHERE  `order_item_name` LIKE  'Photo%' AND  `meta_key` LIKE  '%shipping%name'
```

to get the desired result instead.

Comment: In looking at your suggestion I noticed that I was quoting my table names incorrectly I was using `pm.meta_value` rather than `pm`.`meta_value` etc.  I also aliased everything like you had suggested.  Thanks for your help